# Going through a class in my flutter course but unable to run this following code

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

Im trying to get items from firestore to be shown in Listview on the app but getting "build function returned null.The offending widget is: StreamBuilder,Build functions must never return null". I just want the list 'post' from firstore shown in listview.

> a build function returned null. the offending widget is StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> Build function must never return null.

Please help me out on the issue with app

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'chat_screen';

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User loggedInUser;
  String messageText;

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }



  void messageStream() async {
    await for (var snapShot in _fireStore.collection('messages').snapshots()) {
      for (var message in snapShot.docs) {
        print(message.data());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                messageStream();
                // _auth.signOut();
                // Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                    List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
                    for (var message in messages){
                      final messageText = (message.data as Map<String, dynamic>)['text'];
                      final messageSender = (message.data as Map<String, dynamic>)['sender'];
                      final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                      messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                    } return Column(
                      children: messageWidgets,
                    );
                  }
                },),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _fireStore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': loggedInUser.email
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem as you describe it is that `StreamBuilder` returns `null` even though a `Widget` is expected. Let's focus on that part of your code then.
I cleaned up the formatting to make it easier to understand.

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData) {
      final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
      List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
      for (var message in messages){
        final messageText = (message.data as Map<String, dynamic>)['text'];
        final messageSender = (message.data as Map<String, dynamic>)['sender'];
        final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
        messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
      }
      return Column(
        children: messageWidgets,
      );
    }
  },
),
```

The `builder` function is what shall return a Widget. However, your code starts right off with an `if` statement and the code below will only be executed when `snapshot.hasData` is true. Therefore, the `Column` is only returned in that case.

When the snapshot has not yet finished, i.e. has *no data*, or threw an *error* there is no `else`/fallback section, the code will simply return without giving a `Widget` back to the caller, returning `null`.
This can be solved by providing fallback returns in these cases:

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  ...
  builder: (context, snashot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      ...
      return Column(...);
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Container(
        child: Text("An error occured..."),
       );
    }
    return Container(
      child: Text("No data received yet...Loading..."),
    );
  }
);
```